# The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I beginners to the entity framework, so please bear with me...

How can I relate two objects from different contexts together?

The example below throws the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

```
    [OwnerOnly]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(BlogEntryModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);
        var entry = new BlogEntry
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Content = model.Content,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
            PublishedDate = DateTime.Now,
            User = _userRepository.GetBlogOwner()
        };
        _blogEntryRepository.AddBlogEntry(entry);
        AddTagsToEntry(model.Tags, entry);
        _blogEntryRepository.SaveChange();
        return RedirectToAction("Entry", new { Id = entry.Id });
    }

    private void AddTagsToEntry(string tagsString, BlogEntry entry)
    {
        entry.Tags.Clear();
        var tags = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tagsString)
                       ? null
                       : _tagRepository.FindTagsByNames(PresentationUtils.ParseTagsString(tagsString));
        if (tags != null)
            tags.ToList().ForEach(tag => entry.Tags.Add(tag));             
    }
```

I've read a lot of posts about this exception but none give me a working answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your various repositories `_userRepository`, `_blogEntryRepository`, `_tagRepository` seem to have all their own ObjectContext. You should refactor this and create the ObjectContext outside of the repositories and then inject it as a parameter (for all repositories the same ObjectContext), like so:

```
public class XXXRepository
{
    private readonly MyObjectContext _context;

    public XXXRepository(MyObjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // Use _context in your repository methods.
    // Don't create an ObjectContext in this class
}
```

Comment: Addition to @Slauma's answer: You can't relate objects attached to different contexts. The only way is detach an object from the first context and attach it to the second one. It is much more complex then simply sharing the context among repositories.