# Why on earth does Entity Framework do this?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have a `Car` interface. Each `Car` has a set of parts as `ICollection<Part>`. The `Part` entity has an ID and an optional foreign key reference, `CarId`, in addition to class reference `Public Car Car{ get; set;}`.

So here's the interesting part. Let's say I have a form that displays parts by the `Part ID`. I give the form a `Part` by accessing a repository. `form.Part = repos.Retrieve(PartID)`. Now the form has a reference to the part (and the vehicle that the part belongs to through the part). I create the form by using `context.Forms.Add(form);`

*The database creates a **DUPLICATE** vehicle and part, with their own separate IDs, rather than referencing the ones that already exist.*

Can someone explain why this happens?

---

EDIT

Class Examples for those who want them:

```
public class Form
{
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public Part Part { get; set;}      // Reference to Part
    public int? PartId { get; set; }   // Foreign Key to Part ID
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set;} //Each car has parts
}

public class Part
{
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public Car Car { get; set;}      // Reference to Car
    public int? CarId { get; set; }   // Foreign Key to Car
}
```

Code that will cause this malfunction. Assume Part and Car already exist in the database:

```
form Form = new form();
form.Part = partRepository.Retrieve(5); //gets part with id = 5
context.formRepository.Add(form); // new part created, duplicate of part #5 but with the next available id.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere within those repositories you have a `DbContext` that's used to communicate with the database, right?

The problem is that you are handling the same entity (the `Parts`) through two different repositories. When you add the form to the form repository it probably takes the parts with it. There is no way for that repository to know that those parts are already present in the database and were loaded from the database since they came from another repository/DbContext.

You should really redesign your system so that those repositories either share a common DbContext when used together, or you should make just one repository instead of two.

(Personally I've never understood why people are always creating repositories on top of entity framework. The DbContext *is* an implementation of the repository pattern itself).

Comment: @Anders While `DbContext` could be seen as an implementation of repository pattern, it is not well-suited to be stubbed in tests. So I usually create some kind of (very thin) abstraction layer on top of EntityFramework to be able to stub it out.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev that's definitely a valid reason. I assume that your thin abstraction consists of only *one* repository around the entire DbContext? In that case you won't spoil object tracking. Personally I use transactions for unit tests instead - all tests are wrapped in transaction scopes that's rolled back, leaving the DB in a known state. See more at http://coding.abel.nu/2011/12/using-transactions-for-unit-tests/

Comment: @AndersAbel Yes, of course. And regarding transactions: while this is a valid approach for *integration* tests, it is not a good one for *unit* testing, because your tests begin to depend on database and that's bad in terms of both performance and deployment.

Comment: @AndersAbel Okay, I understand what you're saying, but is there a way to define the two DBContexts to be the same? In the program I'm actually creating I have multiple repositories, each containing their own defined DbContext. Would there be a way on declaration to relate the contexts?

Comment: @proseidon: Don't create the context in the repos, but outside and inject it into all repos, like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5539982/270591 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5823230/270591

Answer (score 0):

Please try marking your Id.s with Data Annotation Key Attribute this will mark them as primary key to avoid duplicates

```
public class Form
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public Part Part { get; set;}      // Reference to Part
    public int? PartId { get; set; }   // Foreign Key to Part ID
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set;} //Each car has parts
}

public class Part
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public Car Car { get; set;}      // Reference to Car
    public int? CarId { get; set; }   // Foreign Key to Car
}
```

Comment: I usually define keys using the fluent api, but this is just an example anyways, meant to show the situation rather than be 100% usable code

Comment: @proseidon Oh, in that case are you using ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave) see link for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.saveoptions